# Python3 multiprocessing core dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a scan of some 8,000 hosts inside a network using SNMP to determine if they have any bridged network interfaces (I work at an ISP, this is internal device tracking). After acquiring a list of all network devices by pulling the ARP table from our routers, I need to scan each host, which is a low-CPU task that mostly consists of waiting around for network latency. So, I used multiprocessing.Pool to spawn 50 workers, and let them scan away. All good, but after a couple of minutes (not at a consistent point in the scan), the process is killed, and I get a core dump. I'm really not sure why it would crash at this point. All I can assume is that the kernel (OpenBSD) is getting mad at this big pile of processes. Anyone have an idea how to just let the scan run?

The relevant code (It's inside a Network class definition, but most of that should be irrelevant.):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from Host import Host

def getHosts(self, ips):
    pool = Pool(50)
    self.hosts = pool.map(initHost, ips)
    return self.hosts

def initHost(ip):
    host = Host(ip)
    host.getInterfaces() # Runs a scan via EasySNMP
    return host
```

If necessary, I could also post the code from the Host class, but it's just some SNMP and property management stuff, and plus it works fine when it's not en masse, so I don't imagine that it's the source of the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a more sane number of process

Comment: Actually, yes! I dropped down to 15 processes, which is frankly going to take ages, and it still crashed, though after a much longer time. I have also increased the number of processes, and it crashes faster, which seems predictable. Moreover, however, since I can see situations in which I would want to run perhaps even more concurrent processes, I'm trying to use this particular wall as an opportunity to learn how to climb. Towards that end, I'm hoping to find out why it's getting killed, so that I can prevent it.

Comment: Are all the processes crashing at once?